# Android App force closing on events like home button push

Tags: android, android-theme, android-2.2-froyo, forceclose

My app plays an mp3 but when I push home button or I switch to portrait from landscape or to landscape from portrait mode the app force closes. I run my app on an a real device with Froyo.

My questions are:

- why does this happen?
- how can I backtrace the reason of a force close?

I am new to both Android and Java.

```
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.AudioTrack;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class AudioPlayManager extends Activity
    implements OnCompletionListener
    {

    private File fileName;
    private volatile boolean playing;
    protected MediaPlayer mp1;

    public AudioPlayManager() {
        super();
        setPlaying(false);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.telek_jobban_lezart);
  mp1.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  mp1.start();
    }

    public void setFileName(File fileName) {
this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public File getFileName() {
return fileName;
    }

    public void setPlaying(boolean playing) {
this.playing = playing;
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
return playing;
    }

    protected void onStop() {
try{
    mp1.stop();
    mp1.release();
}
catch(Exception e){
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mp1.start();
    }

    }
```

My manifest:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.audioplaya2"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.audioplaya2.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

---

UPDATE: SOLUTION

I ran the app on Android 2.2, appearantly it was not build for Android 2.2.

The problem existed on the device but not on the emulator. The emulator runs Android 4.2, the device runs Android 2.2. When I created my project, I left the default SDK setting:

Minimum required SDK: API 8

Target SDK: API 17

Compile with: API 17

Theme: Holo light with dark action bar.

Holo theme requires API 11. I did not get a warning about that until I set all API versions to 8...

This was a surprise for me. The information about The minimum required SDK says: Choose the lowest version of Android that your application will support. Appearantly this is not the real definition of minimum required SDK...

Comment: Have you got access to a simulator such as Eclipse - you'll be able to get a log of what type and where the errors are occurring.

Comment: Please read about the Android Activity life cycle. You will need to code onPause() and onResume().  For the specific problem, please edit your question to include the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: You backtrace a force close by checking your logcat. It will tell you what runtime exception occurred, and at which line. If that's not enough, add some debug statements and/or step through your code using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Override onPause or onStop and try stop the media player before app closes maybe something like this causes failure , 
and for the orientation changing error
put the onCreate code about media player stuff in the onPause (override) method this could help .

Comment: I cannot see why onPause would run when I change orientation... anyway, I have overriden the onPause with the same code as onStop, but no difference... I'll try with LogCat...

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to resolve your problem

- Update your app
- Clear gmail storage data
- clear app cache and data
- Reset smartphone factory setting
- Reset app preferences

You may find complete solutions of given steps from this presentation tutorial

http://www.slideshare.net/StenaGlass/android-force-close-error-fix

I hope you will resolve you problem